# How do i write a batch file that executes commands

Tags: shell, batch-file, putty

I am writing a .bat file to execute commands in putty. I need to load a saved session, then i need to enter a 'terminal id' and press enter, then i need to enter a user name and password. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have an example of what you are trying to do that you could put into the question?

Comment: You need [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) to send key combinations to `putty`.

Comment: I read online about text files with @echo and to run this text file with commands in the command line after you load putty.exe

Comment: `plink` [10 PuTTY PLINK Examples to Automate Remote Linux Commands from Windows Batch Files](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/05/putty-plink-examples/)

Comment: So based on what you read, what have you written so far? What specific problem are you having with the code that you have written?

Comment: I can see at least two other accounts that look like the Original Poster. All three are unregistered. csstudent, please register fully, then follow this link [*I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?*](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts), merge the accounts to regain ownership of the question and stop posting "answers" that are not answers. Take our [tour] to learn how the site works. As the legitimate owner you will be able to edit the question and post comments under it.

Answer (score 0):

There is confusion in your question, and in some answers and comments.

A batch file is a windows command line thing(or a DOS thing) , not a linux thing.

All the examples people have given you are more for running linux commands remotely or for running a batch of linux commands.    Not batch files.

If you ever try using batch files it wouldn't be in the context of a session having logged onto a linux machine.

If you want to run a batch of commands, e.g. a bash file (which has a batch of commands), or a script that runs a batch of commands, some comments mention how to do that. The duplicate question [How to type commands in PuTTY by creating batch file?](https://superuser.com/questions/1103873/how-to-type-commands-in-putty-by-creating-batch-file)  also wrongly mentions batch files in the question, but answers state how to run a batch of commands on a linux system you log into. Mostly if using putty or whatever ssh client, it will load a linux console (unless e.g. the remote machine is windows and running an ssh server that gives a windows command line, like bitvise winsshd). But mostly remote machines people log into tend to be linux or sometimes windows running openssh, and give a linux command line, and so one would run a bash file or script linux can run. Not a batch file.

Really you should learn how to run a batch file on a windows machine. And learn how, when on a linux machine, to run a script e.g. a bash file. And then it will be more clear to you what you want to do when you add something like logging in and automatically running a script.

Comment: I believe that both this and the linked question ask for creating *"Windows batch file that executes command[s] on an SSH server"*. Not for a command that *"executes batch file on an SSH server"*.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yeah but your answer in the linked question isn't explicit that you're talking about a windows batch file   The only commands you mention there are `su, sh, bash, ssh, ftp`    Of those, all are linux based.. none are obviously windows like dir