# Plink using PuTTY colour scheme

Tags: batch, batch-file, putty, plink

I'm trying to open `plink` from a `*.bat` on Windows 10, with the colour scheme defined from an existing session in PuTTY, and while the commands are correctly executing, and the right results displayed, the colour scheme is missing:

```bat
Start /D "C:\PuTTY" plink.exe -load %PUTTY_SESSIONNAME% -m %COMMAND_FILE%
```

Using `putty` instead of `plink` gets the right colour scheme, with commands correctly executed, but the results are *not* displayed right, as all returned text is on a unique line:

```bat
Start /D "C:\PuTTY" putty.exe -load %PUTTY_SESSIONNAME% -m %COMMAND_FILE%
```

How can I solve this issue with `plink`/`putty`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing a command using the [`-m` switch](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-m) disables a pseudo terminal allocation. That make some commands behave differently than in a regular interactive SSH shell session.

Add the [`-t` switch](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pty) to re-enable the pseudo terminal.

```
start /D "C:\PuTTY" putty.exe -t -load %PUTTY_SESSIONNAME% -m %COMMAND_FILE%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin Prikryl, parameter "-t" solves my issue with putty !