# Automatically enable sudo mode when connecting to a VM through putty

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, sudo

I'm using the following shortcut to log into my Ubuntu VM:

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh xxx -pw yyy
```

I tried running `sudo -i` on startup, like so:

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh xxx -pw yyy -m sudo -i
```

However, I receive the error "-i flag requires an argument." I also tried `sudo su`, but I receive error "unable to open sudo file" Is there a way to auto-run `sudo -i` or some equivalent after login?

Comment: login as `root` instead of play such games

Comment: @RomeoNinov is right. Though to answer your literal question, see [How to type commands in PuTTY by creating batch file?](https://superuser.com/q/1103873/213663)